# Invalid Template Argument for vector instantiation

Tags: c++, vector

When I run this code I get "invalid template arguments" error on the last line. Please advise. (I've omitted the rest of the code)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<array>
#include <vector>;
using namespace std;

int fileLineCount(string);
int fileExists(string[],int);

int main() {
    ifstream archiveFile;
    archiveFile.open("StudentRecords.txt");
    int lineCount=fileLineCount("StudentRecords.txt");
    string line;
    vector<string> recordArray;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <vector>;
```

should be

```
#include <vector>
```

and of course you need to close the `}` brace at the end of `main()` (although probably this was a typo). You should also `#include <string>`, although some of your headers seem to include it implicitly (probably `<iostream>`).